# Run the JS loader only at the first website visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader

I'm using a very simple loading Javascript on my page that says something like:

```
$(window).load(function() { $("#spinner").fadeOut("250"); })
```

Then in my CSS

```
#spinner {
display: none;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 100001;
background: white;
}

#spinner:after {
position: fixed;
content: "Loading, it will take a few seconds, please wait";
color: black;
top: 50%;
margin-left: -242px;
}
```

Now I want it to load just the first time someone visit that page instead of everytime (it looks very annoying).

Any help will be really appreciated.
Federico

Comment: if it were me, I would consider using the spinner differently or revisiting your performance optimization if you feel like one is nessecary in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you'll have to store information between page loads using cookies, localstorage, or some database or something.

As mentioned in my comments above however, you might consider rethinking the original design / working on performance if you feel it needs a spinner attached to page load in the first place.